# Kline Calculus Chapter 3, Section 2, Exercise 15(f)

Tags: calculus

The following problem is given:
A wheel of radius 1 foot starts from rest and rotates with a constant acceleration.  After 10 minutes any point on the rim of the wheel has a linear velocity of v = 100 ft/sec.  Find the linear velocity of the point and angular velocity of the wheel after 15 seconds.

The text of the book didn't really go into this kind of problem.  The answer is given as:
linear velocity: (5/2) ft/sec
angular velocity: (5/2) rad/sec

I really don't know quite where to start on this problem.  BTW, Where do I get access to that Math formatting tool that was mentioned.